# защита параметров в запросе jquey. Аутентификация

Tags: javascript, jquery, безопасность

Меня смущает тот факт, что если делать аутентификацию на сайте при помощи запроса jquery, то мы должны допустим написать сервис или php допустим скрипт (не суть важно что) к которому обратиться и передать логин и пароль в JS скрипте. То есть существует JS скрипт в котором находится код отправки jquery запроса - его можно проинспектировать в браузере. Также легко можно воспользоваться моим сервисом и на другом хостинге (лечится проверкой откуда поступил Request запрос). Также можно собрать пакеты снифером и с легкостью проанализировать трафик который в простейшем формате json. Конечно аутентификацию проводит пользователь у себя на компьютере и ему нет смысла анализировать скрипты и чего-то ломать, но у меня чувство стойкое, что в выше написанном тексте есть уезвимости. При том мне по идее надо обратно получить либо идентификатор либо какой либо GUID от сервера что бы я мог его применять в других запросах и это все находится в браузере (но я могу и отсутствовать за компьютером, а злоумышленник не дремлет), это решается сменой GUID с каким-то интервалом времени. Я на самом деле пишу на ASP и микросовт сам заботится о безопасной передаче данных в основном за счет того что все операции производятся на сервере и все шифруется. Но встала зада использовать асинхронные запросы Jquery. Поделитесь опытом. Как по максимум сохранить данные от злоумышленника. Простой пример: аутентифицировались, запомнили идентификатор, спомощью идентификатора заказываем товары, но если идентификатор увести, то можно заказывать товары  от лица потерпевшего.

Comment: Ну во-первых идентификатор нужно передавать лишь только для его использования, но никак не для аутентификации, а для аутентификации передается хэш сессии, в которой уже храниться идентификатор. Во-вторых механизм зщиты уже давно придуман почитай про csrf.

Comment: @sepgg Ну вот использование токкенов кажется единственным способом защиты. Допустим менять его при каждом запросе пользователя на сервер. пользователь отправил запрос на сервер с последним токеном -> я посмотрел в базе -> токен верный -> выполнил запрос -> вернул пользователю новый токен. Но если злоумышленник фильтрует трафик, то он может продолжить мою сессию. Где-то я не уловливаю главной нотки.

Comment: https не пробовали использовать?

Comment: @Visman То есть в  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ServiceJson/WebServiceJson.asmx/changeLogin",  писать полный адрес https//:... ? не пробовал что получится. в таком случае смысл от токенов если трафик шифруется?

Comment: Сайт если по https только работает, то и ajax по https должен работать, думаю. А токен все равно надо использовать.